# Search for duplicates inside an array

Tags: python, arrays, string, string-comparison

I am trying to find duplicates inside an array. 
my array looks like:

```
['LM_Auto', 'LM_Auto', 'LM_Op', 'LM_Op']
```

and much longer with a few thousand of these pairs.

```
def clear_stemmed_LM(collection): 
i = 0
ele = i+1
for i in collection:
    for ele in collection:
        if i == ele:
            del collection[ele]
return collection
```

the error says the list indices must be integers or slices not strings. How can I compare strings in an array?

```
[if x+1 for in x range] #Idea
```

or something similar like this?

Comment: Do you need to find the position of the duplicates for each unique occurrence? Or do you just want to remove the duplicates? Is the order of appearance important?

Comment: To solve this problem you have to use dict or set

Comment: use `set` to remove duplicates

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I just want to remove duplicates. The order doesn't matter, I just need a cleared list which contains each string only once

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to purge the duplicates in the list `collection`, as it seems from the code, `list(set(collection))`.

This is a very, very common and basic issue. I encourage you to Google thoroughly first!

Answer (score 0):

`for i in collection` iters over the items so in `i` you'll find the first string not the index. Use `for i in range(len(collection))` instead

Comment: Jesus, it happens too often to me. Thank you!